# How to pass value to modal in Mobile Angular Ui modal?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using Mobile Angular UI. 
In parent window there is list of category names. I want selected category name should get updated from modal. I am able to display modal. I want to pass selected category item from parent view to modal.

My code in parent view

```
<div ng-controller="CategoryController as TitleCats">
<div ng-repeat="cats in TitleCats.categories">
<a href="" 
      ui-turn-on="titleCatUpdatemodal"
      class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TitleCats.openUpdateModel(cats)"> {{cats.name}}  --> Edit</a>
</div> 
<div ui-content-for="modals">
<div ng-include="'pages/titleCatUpdatemodal.html'"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Modal is

```
<div class="modal" ui-if='titleCatUpdatemodal' ui-state='titleCatUpdatemodal'>
<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" 
            ui-turn-off="titleCatUpdatemodal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

      <p><input type="text" ng-model="cats.name" >{{ cats.name }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button ui-turn-off="titleCatUpdatemodal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button ui-turn-off="titleCatUpdatemodal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When i click button it opens modal but no value!

Anyone please let me know how to get value in modal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also show the JavaScript side of things (eg: your controller, especially the call to create the modal, and the modal controller).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller. you should have something similar to this:

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'templates/myModal.html',
        controller: 'myModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            myData: function () {
                //do stuff
                return stuff;
            }
        }
    });
```

Inside that resolve, you can fill out the function which should then be accessible in your modals controller

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution works in Angular UI but not in Mobile Angular UI.  Finally I have created custom modal service & directive. It works fine for me.